# PHP Socket Disconnecting Randomly

Tags: php

I'm using a PHP Socket to listen on port 6000 for incoming connections and its working perfectly 99% percent of the time but 1% of the time the client is getting a connection error when sending a request to the server. I created a different script to ping the socket on port 6000 every second in an infinite loop and write the result to a log file so I can see if its breaking, and out of 78,000 Successful pings, 23 Failed.

There must be some small logic error with my code which is causing this. If anyone has any ideas its much appreciated.

Socket:

```
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, "0.0.0.0" , 6000) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

if(!socket_listen ($sock , 10))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket listen OK \n";

echo "Waiting for incoming connections... \n";

//start loop to listen for incoming connections
while (true)
{
    //Accept incoming connection - This is a blocking call
    $client =  socket_accept($sock);

    //read data from the incoming socket
    $input = "";
    $input = socket_read($client, 10000000);

     if ($input != "")
     {
        // do my logic here with $input
     }
}
socket_close($sock);
```

EDIT: No, I'm not using CMD to ping. This is my PHP script which is doing the pinging:

```
<?php
$host = '0.0.0.0';
$port = 6000;
$waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1;
while(true)
{
   if($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds))
   {   
       $file = 'log.txt';
       $current = file_get_contents($file);
       $today = date("Y-m-d_H:i:s");  
       $current .= $today . " - SUCCESS\n";
       file_put_contents($file, $current);
   } 
   else 
   {
       $file = 'log.txt';
       $current = file_get_contents($file);
       $today = date("Y-m-d_H:i:s");  
       $current .= $today . " - FAILED\n";
       file_put_contents($file, $current);
   } 
   fclose($fp);
   sleep(1);
}
?>
```

For an actual transaction, the client is only connected for a split second while it sends through an xml request in raw text, then it does some logic which takes less than a second. Since its failing on the ping test though, that means my listener is breaking for a second for one reason or another does it not?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly.

You say about 0,03% of your pings failed. Is this your problem? If these are real pings (ping.exe from cmd.exe) then it has nothing to do with your logic. It's the network. (Is the host on WIFI?)

If you are convinced it's your logic:
If someone connects, how long is he connected? And what happens to new requests while connected to the previous client? I think you may find your answer here.

Also try to do a test with a client that continuously connects and sends dummy data, in stead of pinging. And log what responses the client is receiving.

Comment: I updated my question with my script for pinging. And yes, this is my problem. I need the socket to accept 100% of requests. It makes no sense why only a few would randmoly not work.

Comment: Your pinger waits 1 second before giving up. That could also just indicate that 0.03% needed more than 1 second to connect. Try logging $errStr and $errCode too. Was it a timeout or something else?

Comment: Ah good point. I've updated that to give it a 5 second timeout and echoing the errors. I'll see if there's and more errors and keep you posted.

Comment: @tajonny07 did you get somewhere with it?

Comment: I'm still having the issue. Even with the 5 second timeout every now and then it still comes back failed to connect. It attempts to connect for 5 seconds then gives up. But the server isnt 'down' for 5 seconds, because before when I was testing with a 1 second timeout, it would fail one second, then succeed the next. I suppose this could be a problem with my server.. but I don't see how. I'm running CentOS and upblocked the port in the iptables.

Comment: Its just weird because usually these things either work - or they dont. This is working perfectly 99% of the time, but then 1 out of 100 it seems just decides to timeout when connecting to the server :S This is quite frustrating.